# How do I generate random keys for test.check?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, test.check

I'm using test.check to generate a hashmap. I want one key to be a random numeric keywords This is what I tried

```
(gen/hash-map
  :16 gen/nat
  :1041 gen/string
  (keyword (str gen/nat)) gen/string)
```

This works fine for the first two keys, but gen/sample returns a function for the last key instead of a value. An output from gen/sample  `{:16 1, :1041 "»", :clojure.test.check.generators.Generator@3daf97b7 "u"}`

Comment: Why a keyword from a number?  Is this just an example? Keywordizing any nonsense is usually a bad idea...

Comment: Usually people who do this think that the only valid map keys are keywords.

Comment: @cfrick - it mimics the data which is a very large map of numbers that are keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using `gen/bind`

```clj
user> (require '[clojure.test.check.generators :as gen])
nil
user> (gen/sample (gen/bind gen/nat
                            #(gen/hash-map
                              :16 gen/nat
                              :1041 gen/string
                              (keyword (str %)) gen/string)))
({:16 0, :1041 "", :0 ""}
 {:16 1, :1041 "—", :1 "Õ"}
 {:16 1, :1041 "~", :2 "{"}
 {:16 0, :1041 "", :0 ""}
 {:16 1, :1041 "}", :2 "š¤#"}
 {:16 4, :1041 "", :4 "ÂêÃ"}
 {:16 6, :1041 "¯¾ùPêà", :1 "xaÝ$"}
 {:16 1, :1041 "", :4 "ž"}
 {:16 7, :1041 "", :3 "Ù¡"}
 {:16 3, :1041 "‚«¤s", :5 "Æ¶oÒA“"})
user>
```

And here is one using `gen/fmap`

```clj
user> (gen/sample (gen/fmap (fn [[m n s]] (assoc m (keyword (str n)) s))
                            (gen/tuple (gen/hash-map
                                        :16 gen/nat
                                        :1041 gen/string)
                                       gen/nat gen/string)))
({:16 0, :1041 "", :0 ""}
 {:16 0, :1041 "", :1 "Ô"}
 {:16 2, :1041 "`", :0 "V²"}
 {:16 1, :1041 "X", :2 "b"}
 {:16 3, :1041 "JÓ", :2 ""}
 {:16 2, :1041 "", :2 ""}
 {:16 2, :1041 "", :2 "×kîj"}
 {:16 0, :1041 "", :0 ""}
 {:16 5, :1041 "ÎÖ", :0 ":üv-`"}
 {:16 8, :1041 "¬KéÎêo\r", :4 "ÆÌ"})
user>
```

In such cases, you have to use either `gen/fmap` or `gen/bind`.  Both of them allow you to manipulate the output of a generator.  If you want to return a generator, then use `gen/bind`.  If you want to return a value, then use `gen/fmap`.  Both `gen/fmap` and `gen/bind` take two arguments, one of which is a generator, and the other argument is a function that takes the value generated by the first as its input and returns either a generator (for `gen/bind`) or a value (for `gen/fmap`).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [clojure.test.check.generators/fmap](http://clojure.github.io/test.check/clojure.test.check.generators.html#var-fmap) to apply your functions (`str`, `keyword`) to your generator.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `fmap`. It should require `bind`.

Comment: `bind` is more appropriate in this example, but you can use `fmap` as well.